# How to manually deploy serverless nodejs project in aws lambda?

Tags: serverless, serverless-framework, aws-serverless, serverless-architecture

Hi I have ran serverless package --stage test command in my local
then a .serverless folder is created
.serverless folder content:

- cloudformation-template-create-stack.json
- cloudformation-template-update-stack.json
- my-backend.zip
- serverless-state.json

My doubt is do i need to upload all these files to aws lambda while doing manual serverless deploy? Please help

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything with these files manually. Whenever `serverless deploy` is ran, it will handle all uploading for you. If you want to deploy with prebuild package, you can use `--package` flag to `serverless deploy`.